# How To Revert Commits In Git?

Tags: git

I am a little confused about the different ways to revert commits in GIT.

From my understanding `git reset --hard HEAD~1` will destroy the last commit as if it never happened.

Is `git reset --hard HEAD~1` equivalent to `git reset --hard HEAD@{1}`?

Also, does `git reset --hard 12345` destroy all commits after commit 12345?

Comment: `~1` means first child for commit. `@{1}` means previous known position of given branch. So just after a commit it will be same thing, but after rebase or reset it will be completely different thing.

Comment: @MarekR  This helps.  I understand  the ```~1``` comment.  Can you give an example of when you would use ```@{1}```?

Comment: Here is [documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitrevisions#_specifying_revisions).